# How python3 uses avconv through ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I import paramiko to use ssh to send command to my VPS. Command 'avconv' works well on my VPS. But in python, sending it through ssh, its stdout is ' ', it does nothing.

```
def sshclient_execmd(hostname, port, username, password, execmd):    
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.log')
    s = paramiko.SSHClient()  
    s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())  
    s.connect(hostname=hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command (execmd)
    info = stdout.read().decode()
    s.close()
    return info


def merge(hostname, port, username, password, filename):
    execmd = 'avconv -i \''+filename+'.mp4\' -i \''+filename+'.m4a\' -c copy \''+filename+'.mp4.mp4\''
    info = sshclient_execmd(hostname, port, username, password, execmd)
    print(info)
```

Comment: Where are you calling these functions?

Comment: just using them in main()

Comment: How do you know that avconv writes to stdout?

Comment: Stdout is not the major problem. I use avconv to merge a video with the sound. I check the VPS, it doesn't do it. This confuses me.

Comment: Are you sure that you can `print(execmd)` and it is the exact same format you expect to run via the shell?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure, It works through ssh shell.

Comment: Is just `avconv` the issue? Like, can you run other commands? I see you are ignoring `stderr` completely, so can you check that?

Comment: Thank you! I find error information in stderr. Now I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow 'avconv' becomes 'command not found.' So using its path like '/usr/local/bin/avconv' can fix it.